# How to Trap Floating-Point Exceptions On Rosetta 2

Tags: clang, apple-m1, floating-point-exceptions, rosetta-2

In a related question, [How to trap floating-point exceptions on M1 Macs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69059981/how-to-trap-floating-point-exceptions-on-m1-macs/71792418?noredirect=1), someone wanted to understand how to make the following code work natively on macOS hosted by a machine using the M1 processor:

```
#include <cmath>        // for sqrt()                                           
#include <csignal>      // for signal()                                         
#include <iostream>
#include <xmmintrin.h>  // for _mm_setcsr                                       

void fpe_signal_handler(int /*signal*/) {
  std::cerr << "Floating point exception!\n";
  exit(1);
}

void enable_floating_point_exceptions() {
 _mm_setcsr(_MM_MASK_MASK & ~_MM_MASK_INVALID);
 signal(SIGFPE, fpe_signal_handler);
}

int main() {
  const double x{-1.0};
  std::cout << sqrt(x) << "\n";
  enable_floating_point_exceptions();
  std::cout << sqrt(x) << "\n";
}
```

I am looking at this from another angle, and want to understand why it doesn't work using Rosetta 2. I compiled it using the following command:

```
clang++ -g -std=c++17 -arch x86_64 -o fpe fpe.cpp
```

When I run it, I see the following output:

```
nan
nan
```

Mind you, when I do the same thing on a Intel-based Mac, I see the following output:

```
nan
Floating point exception!
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to trap floating-point exceptions on Rosetta 2?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the difference in trapping on Intel using:

```
_mm_setcsr(_MM_MASK_MASK & ~_MM_MASK_INVALID);
```

and trapping on Apple Silicon using:

```
fegetenv(&env);
env.__fpcr = env.__fpcr | __fpcr_trap_invalid;
fesetenv(&env);
```

it seems more likely it is a bug in the Rosetta implementation.

Comment: Confirmed: it seems like Rosetta2 doesn't support FPU exceptions